# Reccuring Notice in Civicrm

Tags: drupal, error

I am getting this recurring error in CiviCRM when I do various task, is this something I should be worried about?

> Notice: Undefined index: path in
>   CRM_Core_BAO_Navigation::getMenuName() (line 474 of
>   /var/www/elmsln/domains/community/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/Navigation.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not something to be worried about. It is a warning that somewhere in the code a syntax rule is not correct, but this does not affect the actual processing. You should be worried if you get a yellow message with 'Error', 'Notice' is irritating but nothing to get worried about.

Answer (score 1):

Checking the code, it seems likely that one of your menu items contains an invalid url. Have you made any customizations to the CiviCRM menubar?